# Numpy matrix of pairwise sums

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, syntax

Somewhat often I am in the situation where I have two one-dimensional arrays X and Y, and I would like to construct a matrix Z defined by

```
  Z[i,j]=X[i]+Y[j]
```

Now this is not difficult to do, for example

```
aux=np.outer(np.ones(len(X)), X)
aux2=np.outer(Y,np.ones(len(Y)))
Z=aux+aux2
```

My question is whether there is a less verbose way to get this result?

Comment: `np.add.outer(X,Y)`?

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick, but I don't quite understand how it works. What does the "add.outer" syntax mean?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html might help.